# Magento change complete admin url

Tags: url, admin, magento

I need to change my admin url completely. For example, my store url is `www.domain.com` and for admin access its: `www.domain.com/admin`
I want to change `www.domain.com/admin` to `www.newdomain.com/admin` but want to access the store front on the old url `www.domain.com`. Is this possible in Magento?

Comment: This question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095047/creating-an-admin-url-for-magento-that-is-admin-magentostore-com-not-admin).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it easier in the backend:

```
System > Config > Admin > Admin base url(?)

use own admin url
use own admin path
```

I have only a german magento at the moment, but you find it in the config at the end of the menu on the left side (Admin)

Answer (score 0):

Step1:- Go To root folder than

```
app/etc/local.xml
```

open local.xml file and change below "CDATA[admin]" code.

```
   <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

NOTE:- use only small character.

Step2:- go to var/ folder and delete cache folder.  Now open admin with you're new admin name url..