# What are the step to go through to set up a working development environement for Magento?

Tags: php, magento, continuous-integration, development-environment

Magento is a e-commerce application based on Zend Framework, dive in Magento is sometimes not so easy due to the lack of documentation.

When I take back a project, I've to go through several step to get it working :

1. Check it out from any CVS
2. Set up the database from the most recent dump of the production server (if any)
3. Set up the `app/etc/local.xml`
4. Replace `web/secure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` in database
5. Adjust `.htaccess` setting according to my environment
6. Set up errors/local.xml from config sample
7. Allow `display_errors`

Obviously, at the first step of my development work-flow, I want to display all errors, all exceptions, log every things, etc.

I may have forgot a lot of thing, here is the reason of my question, I'm looking to write kind of cheat sheet from the answer to have the step when I want to set up my Magento Development Environment, and why not write a script.

Answer (score 2):

As an extra for your checklist:

Setup bootstrapping files for unit testing or install [PHPUnitTestSuite extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Ecommerce+Developers/extension/5717/ecomdev_phpunit)

Comment: Wow, I like the idea very much, I'll definitely give it a try, both PHPUnit + Selenium tests would be so much an help in such dev.

Answer (score 1):

Add a local.xml file to the /errors/ folder which sets error output to print. Find a sample in the /errors/ folder.

Backup your db to go back later to this state.

Set the error settings to `error_reporting(-1);` to show every error, this helps you also to extend Magento in the correct way, because you then only can extend original Magento classes with the correct signature of its methods!

Check out the [Boilerplate for Magento](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-boilerplate/), it helps you to layout your shop!

Comment: what is this function error_settings()? is it part of the Magento helper functions? I dunno this one.

Answer (score 1):

You want more details(sql query's, files used, time of request split up by function.) and more debug power try this : http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/
I'm using it in active development and it's more than great.

Comment: I know well this plugin, never thought to use it within a Magento project though

Answer (score 1):

You might want to review some of the answers to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3740858/336905).

Hope this helps,
JD